# rq in Docker: "Could not resolve a Redis connection" with an otherwise working redis connection

Tags: docker, redis, docker-compose, python-rq

I feel like I'm doing what every other question on this has an accepted answer suggesting. But I am unable to get a Flask app using [rq](https://python-rq.org/) to successfully connect to redis despite successfully connecting to redis using a bare `Redis` instance.

In my app code from my `web` service:

```py
from rq import Queue
from rq import Queue
from redis import Redis

redis = Redis(host="redis", db=0, socket_connect_timeout=10, socket_timeout=10)

# ...

        visits = redis.incr("counter")
        print(f"visits: {visits}")

        q = Queue(redis);
        q.enqueue(my_worker.work)
```

and logs:

```
visits: 11
rq.connections.NoRedisConnectionException: Could not resolve a Redis connection
```

The `visits` counter is working properly, so clearly there is a working Redis connection. Yet the `Queue` instance is unable to use it. No difference if I initialize a separate `Redis` instance for the `Queue` (or leave the counter stuff out entirely).

I'm running this stack using `docker stack deploy` with a `docker-compose.yml` that is not too modified from the beginner's tutorial:

```
version: "3"
services:
  web:
    image: ozydingo/workers-web:latest
    deploy: #...
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    networks:
      - webnet
  worker:
    image: ozydingo/workers-worker:latest
    deploy: #...
    networks:
      - webnet
  redis:
    image: redis
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
    volumes:
      - "/home/docker/data:/data"
    deploy: #...
    networks:
      - webnet
#...
networks:
  webnet:
```

How should I interpret an error from `Queue` claiming no Redis connection could be resolved when my `redis` instance is telling me otherwise?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I take for granted that the [official documentation](https://python-rq.org/) should be followed, the correct syntax to create a queue object is:

```
my_queue = Queue(connection=my_redis_connection_object)
```

So change your line

```
# /!\ Wrong /!\
q = Queue(redis)
```

to the following

```
q = Queue(connection=redis)
```

--

Supplementary note: Nothing to do with your problem, but you have a duplicate import for `Queue` at the top of your file.